# Install go package with dependencies

Tags: go

I had some issues with gopath configuration. I was able to resolve the go path issue. But getting this error...

```
[root@localhost mysqlbeat]# go get  github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat

# github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/beater
/root/go/src/src/github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/beater/mysqlbeat.go:289:7: b.Events undefined (type *beat.Beat has no field or method Events)
/root/go/src/src/github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/beater/mysqlbeat.go:303:7: b.Events undefined (type *beat.Beat has no field or method Events)
/root/go/src/src/github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/beater/mysqlbeat.go:326:5: b.Events undefined (type *beat.Beat has no field or method Events)
```

How do I correctly install go package along with all it's dependencies?

---

Update:

I downloaded the package and tried to run it.Different error this time...

```
[root@localhost mysqlbeat]# make
go build
can't load package: /root/go/src/src/github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/main.go:8:2: non-standard import "github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat/beater" in standard package "src/github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat"
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [How to Build](https://github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat#how-to-build) section on `README.md` on `mysqlbeat`.

`mysqlbeat` uses Glide for dependency management. [Check this for installing glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide).

After installing Glide, clone the `mysqlbeat` repository and run:

```
$ glide update --no-recursive
$ make
```

If you still want to import this repository by `go get`, clone the repo and then run `go get ./...` from its root directory.